# Request processing failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 48 out of bounds for length 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, mysql-workbench, jpa, intellij-idea

Estoy aprendiendo un poco de JAVA spring boot para la creación de una API, entonces quiero buscar un docente de los que tengo regitrado en mi base de datos, sin embargo al ejecutar el método findById me da un error extraño; java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, sé que se ejecuta cuando intento acceder a un indice que no existe en un arreglo. Identifiqué que es cuando encuentra el ID, por ejemplo en la base tengo el docente con id 1, si hago el findById(1) debería traérmelo, pero me tira la siguiente excepción: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 48 out of bounds for length 2, en cambio si pongo un id que no esté en la base de datos, no me genera ninguna excepción. No sé qué pueda ser, y no encuentro nada con este problema. Comparto el código de las clases:

La clase del repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DocenteRepository extends JpaRepository<Docente, Integer> {
}
```

DOCENTE:

```
package com.project.api.domain.tutor;

import com.project.api.domain.estudiante.Estudiante;
import com.project.api.domain.persona.DatosRegistroPersona;
import com.project.api.domain.persona.Persona;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
//JPA
@Table(name = "Docentes")
@Entity(name = "Docente")
public class Docente extends Persona {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_docente")
    Integer idDocente;
    Rol rol;
    public Docente(DatosRegistroDocente docente) {
        this.setNombre(docente.persona().nombre());
        this.setDireccion(docente.persona().direccion());
        this.setCorreo(docente.persona().correo());
        this.setTelefono(docente.persona().telefono());
        this.setNacimiento(docente.persona().nacimiento());
        this.setRol(docente.rol());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Docente{" +
                "IdDocente: " + this.getIdDocente() +
                "nombre: " + this.getNombre() +
                "direccion: " + this.getDireccion() +
                "correo: " + this.getCorreo() +
                "telefono: " + this.getTelefono() +
                "rol: " + this.getRol() +
                "}";
    }
}
```

La clase del endpoint get en donde estoy probando la funcionalidad:

```
package com.project.api.controller;
import com.project.api.domain.DatosDTO;
import com.project.api.domain.tutor.Docente;
import com.project.api.domain.tutor.DocenteRepository;
import com.project.api.infra.errores.ValidacionIntegridad;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.apache.coyote.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/prueba")
public class PruebaController {
    @Autowired
    DocenteRepository docenteRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity recibirDatos(){
        Optional<Docente> docenteOptional;

        try{
           docenteOptional = docenteRepository.findById(1);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("FALLO EN EL FINDBY, ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        //Si logra pasar del findbyOd
        if (docenteOptional.isPresent()) {
            Docente docente = docenteOptional.get();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(docente);
        } else {
            // Manejo de caso en el que no se encontró el docente con el ID proporcionado
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}
```

Estaba debugeando el código, y le puse un try catch justo a la sentencia que siento que me presentaba el error, el findById, y en efecto de esa línea surge el error. Entonces, al ejecutar el endpoint get me tira la excepción de RunTime, tal como lo habia planeado. Comparto el resultado: java.lang.RuntimeException: FALLO EN EL FINDBY, ERROR: Index 48 out of bounds for length 2